how to automate invoice input using docxptl
so I use docxptl to automate the process of making invoices. but, it does not input to my word file. i already follow the tutorial thoroughly, but it does not change anything. here is my code :
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import csv

appt_item = input("Masukan Nama : ")

list_print_bill = []

with open("./xxx/xxx.csv", 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Appt'] == appt_item:
            list_print_bill.append(appt_item)
            list_print_bill.append(row['Patient'])
            list_print_bill.append(row['Medical Treatment'])
            list_print_bill.append(row['Date'])

with open("./xxx/xxx.csv", 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    obat = row['Medical Treatment']
    for row in reader:
        if row['Medical Treatment'] == obat:
            list_print_bill.append(row['Price'])

tuple_data = tuple(list_print_bill)
print(tuple_data)

doc=DocxTemplate("./xxx/xxx.docx")
for value_tuple in tuple_data[0:]:
    doc.render({"APPT": value_tuple[0],
                "PATIENT":value_tuple[1],
                "MEDICAL TREATMENT": value_tuple[2],
                "DATE": value_tuple[3],
                "PRICE": value_tuple[4],
    })


    doc.save("Invoice.docx")

Here is my docx file :
It did generate a new file but nothing change. Is there anything that I do wrong here?
